# Stepper motor driver board

Tags: power-supply, motor

Hi I'm planning to make a motor driving circuit on a perfboard. I'm new to electronics so please bear with me. 
In the past I've wired up stepper motors and run them correctly using microcontrollers. But I made the circuit on breadboards. Now I wanna make something permanent. 
 I'm using the l293d to drive a stepper motor. It has two power supply inputs one is 5v and the other is the motor power supply. Should I split the motor power supply , one line going to the as the motor supply, and the other going to a 7805 regulator to the 5v VCC or should I separate the two power lines?

Comment: What is the motor supply voltage?  What is the nature of the power source? Battery? Mains-operated supply? etc. What does "split the supply" or "separate the two power lines" mean here?  How does making the circuit "permanent" on a perfboard make it any different than creating the circuit on a breadboard?

Comment: Motor power supply is a lab bench power supply at 9V. What I mean by splitting here is.. Basically I just was wondering if I can make a 5v supply to the l293d ic from the 9v lab bench supply. Normally the stepper motor draws a considerable amount of current. I'm trying to ask if I can use  9v supply and regulate it to 5v to use for the VCC of the l293d(pin 16).

Comment: Please update your question with the extra facts about the bench power supply, and your specific question. That helps the community to understand the same question without having to read all the comments.

Comment: Beware that the L293D has high internal losses which means it has a low maximum current and will tend to heat up.

Answer (score 1):

A small 78L05 regulator would do the job. The L293D requires only around 35mA of 5V, and the 78L05 will source 100mA. The 78L05 is a very small device in a TO92 case (like a transistor).